# Spring security http and authentication-provider not declared

Tags: spring, spring-security

I was trying to integrating Spring security into my existing project. The tools that I am using are:

1. Spring 2.5.6.SEC03
2. spring-security-core 3.1.1.RELEASE
3. JDK 7.

In spring configuration, I have this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/messagePost.htm*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</http>

<authentication-provider>
  <user-service>
    <user name="user1" password="1111" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
  </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</beans:beans>
```

But there is an error on this spring configuration:

1. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'authentication-provider'.
2. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.

May I know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MaKe these changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/messagePost.htm*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  </http>

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="user1" password="1111" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I have done the following changes

1. Changed your xmlns schema from `"http://springframework.org/schema/security"`to `"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"` (added www :D)
2. I have enclosed the `<authentication-provider>` namespace inside a `<authentication-manager>` namespace.

Comment: May I know `<authentication-manager>` is a new feature in Spring 3?

Comment: I haven't used spring security < 3. So i am not sure about it. You can check more on this [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html).